# OAuth2 login to SoundCloud recently returns Error Domain=NXOAuth2HTTPErrorDomain Code=401 "HTTP Error: 401"

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I am trying to log into my SoundCloud account on an iOS app I develop using the Objective-C SoundCloudAPI framework https://github.com/sangtn/SoundCloudAPI

This worked like a charm the last time I used it but by today I am getting the following error message:

> Error Domain=NXOAuth2HTTPErrorDomain Code=401 "HTTP Error: 401"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP Error: 401}

Using the same credentials (email and psw) grants me access on the web platform and on the SoundCloud iOS app.

I cannot find any recent changes on the SoundCloud platform nor does their status page indicate any malfunction, so I am asking if anyone is experiencing this as well and if someone has found a cause of this issue?!

Thanks!

Comment: also having this issue

Comment: loggin in via facebook works, but not normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks soundcloud fixed the issue

Comment: Indeed it seems to be fixed. Thanks for calling in!

Answer (score 0):

Having issues as of last night with my app logging in as well. I've Tweeted and emailed - seems like this could be a broader issue on their side.

Comment: I seem to be having issues authenticating users reckon this is also linked to the issue?