# Soundcloud login on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, soundcloud

In the past I've used this library: https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI

However login is no longer working. Using the facebook login does the trick, but not with normal credentials. Anyone know of an alternative or an official way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSURLConnections to hit a web service that utilizes the SoundCloud API. https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication

Comment: This requires me to build a viewcontroller where the user puts in their username and password though, correct?

Comment: Yes it would. (Extra characters to meet requirements.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems SoundCloud is currently having an issue with their API, and it is not possible to log in, indeed. Here is another question concerning this problem:

[OAuth2 login to SoundCloud recently returns Error Domain=NXOAuth2HTTPErrorDomain Code=401 "HTTP Error: 401"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243274)

And concerning the CocoaSoundCloudAPI, it is not supported by SoundCloud anymore. There are a couple of alternatives you may want to try, such as these:

https://github.com/MrStofkat/LibSoundCloud-iOS

https://github.com/delannoyk/SoundcloudSDK

Comment: is this a problem for everyone using the api?

Comment: I believe so, but it was a transient problem and now seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

SoundCloud seems to had fixed the issue. Everything seems to work normally again!